# I get an error while searching for a reference in another sheet within a With block

Tags: excel, vba

This is for a vba script within Excel. I am getting an Error trying to search in another sheet inside a With block that finds a reference value

I am not familiar with vba scripting in Excel. I read some code snippets from this site and tried it out. Not sure why do I keep getting this error

> Run-time error '91'.

I find out that this means "Object variable or With block variable not set"

```
Public Sub ReplaceCovCfg()

    Dim sValToFind As String
    Dim rSearchRange As Range
    Dim sFirstAdd As String
    Dim rFoundCell As Range
    Dim rAllFoundCells As Range
    Dim sSbmId As String
    sValToFind = "Reference"
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Internal_Report")
        Set rSearchRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With rSearchRange
         Set rFoundCell = .Find(sValToFind, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
         If Not rFoundCell Is Nothing Then
            sFirstAdd = rFoundCell.Address
            Do

                sMessage = sMessage & rFoundCell.Row & ", "

                'Create a range of found cells.
                If Not rAllFoundCells Is Nothing Then
                    Set rAllFoundCells = Union(rAllFoundCells, rFoundCell)
                Else
                    Set rAllFoundCells = rFoundCell
                End If
                Set rFoundCell = .FindNext(rFoundCell)

                ' search in previous records
                sSbmId = rFoundCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
                    Set lookupSearchRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
                    With lookupSearchRange
                        Set lookupFoundCell = .Find(sSbmId, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
                    ' End With

                        If Not lookupFoundCell Is Nothing Then
                            rFoundCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = "Old"
                        Else
                            rFoundCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = "New"
                        End If
                    End With
                End With

            Loop While rFoundCell.Address <> sFirstAdd
         End If
    End With

    rAllFoundCells.Offset(0, 1).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2")

End Sub
```

Keep getting this error:

> Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

for this line:

```
Set lookupFoundCell = .Find(sSbmId, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
```

If I remove this line, and the following `If` block, the script manages to run without error.

If I replace `sSbmId` with a constant string (like "blahblah", I still get the same error.

Just for curiosity's sake, if I replace `sSbmId` with `sValToFind` (which doesn't make sense, the macro runs without error.

Any ideas?

Comment: you've not defined the type of `lookupFoundCell`.  I'd follow error checking advice [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/object-variable-or-with-block-variable-not-set)

Comment: @Andrew that link is to a .Net page, not VBA.  While it's good advice to Dim all variables,  that won't cause the error OP reports

Comment: @user probably `rSearchRange` is `Nothing` after the first Find.  Add a `If Not rSearchRange Is Nothing Then`

Comment: Did "... .FindNext(rFoundCell)"  really find anything? put debug on next line and then add watch to see what was gotten.

Comment: In step by step run (F8), I see that after first iteration in DO, in second iteration, I see that at the line:    Set rFoundCell = .FindNext(rFoundCell)      rFoundCell is changed to Nothing. This does not happen if I dont have the block starting from      With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")

Answer (score 1):

The `set` assignment requires an object, but you haven't declared (dimensioned) `lookupFoundCell`. It is therefore being defaulted to a variant.

The Range.Find method returns a Range object so you can dimension your variable like this:

```
Dim lookupFoundCell as Range
```

Always use `Option Explicit` in your VBA projects and then you'll get better error checking. In this case you would have seen that you had not declared the variable.

Comment: While this is always good practice (and prevents numerous *other* issues), it is not actually the cause of this one

Answer (score 0):

Step through line-by-line with <kbd>F8</kbd>, and you will see that the issue is actually here:

```
If Not rAllFoundCells Is Nothing Then
    Set rAllFoundCells = Union(rAllFoundCells, rFoundCell) 'This Line Errors
Else
    Set rAllFoundCells = rFoundCell
End If
```

The reason is quite simple: your *first* `rFoundCell` is from `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Internal_Report")`, so `rAllFoundCells` is also on `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Internal_Report")`

However, your *second* `rFoundCell` is from `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")` - you are trying to create `Union` of cells from **different worksheets**.  This is not a permitted action.

To see this more clearly (but **not** fix the code - you need to decide what you are *actually* trying to do and rework your underlying logic first), use this:

```
If Not rAllFoundCells Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "rAllFoundCells: " & rAllFoundCells.Worksheet.Name
    Debug.Print "rFoundCell:" & rFoundCell.Worksheet.Name
    Set rAllFoundCells = Union(rAllFoundCells, rFoundCell) 'This Line Errors
    Debug.Print "This line will only show if there is no error"
Else
    Set rAllFoundCells = rFoundCell
End If
```

You can view the Debug output in the VBE Immediate Window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>)

Comment: Not sure I got it. Why would the second rFoundCell be from ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")? My intention is to have lookupFoundCell from ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3"). Thats why I had these statements in the With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3") block:
                    Set lookupSearchRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
                    With lookupSearchRange
                        Set lookupFoundCell = .Find(sSbmId, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
                    ' End With

Comment: Is it because the whole block is under With rSearchRange? What should be the right way to search the value from first sheet "Internal_Report" in the second sheet "Sheet 3"?